# DIP not showing lookup data column values for selected columns only?

Tags: dip

Document Library (multi content types enabled).

- Has multi content types attached with Word, Excel templates.
- All Content Types/Templates source the same metadata (Site Columns).
- The Content Type(s) data columns (4) are `Lookup` Site Column types.
- Two lookup data columns lookup independently to two separate lists. Each list includes a single data column with multi values enabled for selection. (These values are displayed in DIP for selection without issue.)
- Other two lookup data columns lookup to another list with multiple data columns, but each are defined to display a select column from that list (the selected columns are enabled for multi value section).

In DIP, a field is shown for each of the two data columns, one shows check boxes but no values next to them and the other shows a single value next to a checkbox and the following checkboxes do not show values.  If the checkboxes are selected, even for the one that has a single value on save/checkin the values are not displayed in library. However, after save to library the doc properties are editied the metadata form displayed will show the values for the two data columns and allow selection and application to the document in the library.

Can the lookup values in the DIP be displayed correctly at initial tagging rather than in post?